# Why is new diverter faucet leaking?

Tags: plumbing, leak, faucet, bathtub, diverter

Shower faucet leaks after replacement

I replaced the faucet with diverter with a brand new one. For what it's worth, the pipe (stub) looks super corroded. I unscrewed the stub, cleaned it with some dental tools and steel wool. Once I got all the gunk off of it and cleaned the threads, I wrapped it in new Teflon tape and screwed it back into the fitting.

I turned the stub until it was between 3.75 - 4 inches from the wall. I wrapped the protruding threads in Teflon tape and installed brand new diverter and it still leaks from the mouth of the faucet with the diverter pulled up.

What do? Faulty faucet? How did I mess it up?

Here are some pictures of the female end of the pipe as it exits from the wall and the male stub before opening cleaned it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The stub out pipe has some bits missing from it - those could be leaking. Did you wrap 1-2 layers of tape around _both_ ends of the stubout? Did you wrap the tape in the correct direction so it didn't get lifted as you screwed things in?

Comment: Looks like the wise move would be to get a new nipple.  Also try some pipe joint compound instead of teflon tape.

Comment: Also, since it's tapered, make sure the compound or tape is applied to *all* the threads!

Comment: See https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/269215/18078 it's perfectly normal for there to be *a trickle* from the diverter itself. Large flows would indicate  a problem. flows from the part against the wall would suggest the bad threads are the problem; flow out the spout in small amounts is normal. As for the nipple, take it to the plumbing supply and get a new one, but that won't affect a normal shower diverter's normal level of imperfect seal.